# Bootstrap collapse accordion with head and body seperated

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to make an accordion with bootstrap. But the head and body must be separated.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <h4>
    number of invoices : 
    <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#day">Day</span> | 
    <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#week">Week</span> | 
    <span  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#month">Month</span>
    </h4>

    <p id="day" class="panel-collapse collapse in">Da </p>
    <p id="week" class="panel-collapse collapse">Week</p>
    <p id="month" class="panel-collapse collapse">Month</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Here is how it is supposed to look like : http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/11/ynzc.png   In red is the accordion

Comment: Read the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example). There is no panel in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help.

```
  <div id="accordion">
  <p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#day" aria-expanded="false">
          Day
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#week" aria-expanded="false" >
          Week
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#month" aria-expanded="false" >
          Month
      </button>                           
  </p>
  <div class="card">    
    <div id="day" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Day
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div id="week" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Week
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div id="month" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        month
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it's not an accordion. I want to show only one paragraph at a time.

Comment: @Youcef Lebid, I just updated my previous answer code. Does it help?

Comment: When I tested it i could open multiple card at the same time. I need to only open one at a time. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Youcef Lebid, That was the first answer I posted. I updated that code. Test the new code and see if it helps.